# How can i get this theme toggle code working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, tailwind-css

I’m having issues with getting light/dark theme toggle working. The source html, css, Javascript code is below, the html is correct and the button is on the page. Just when i toggle it does nothing: the background page colour doesn't go from white to black and vice versa. What is missing/wrong. I suspect its the Javascript and/or CSS.

i tried simplifying the javascript and css but hasn't worked. The page by default should be white then turn black when toggle is well toggled and vice versa.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme');

    // Function to toggle theme
    function toggleTheme() {
        if (themeToggle.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        }
    }

    // Event listener for theme toggle change
    themeToggle.addEventListener('change', toggleTheme);
});
```

```css
.theme__toggle:checked ~ body {
  background-color: black; /* Dark mode background color */
  color: #fff; /* Text color for dark mode */
}

/* Light mode */
.theme__toggle:not(:checked) ~ body {
  background-color: white; /* Light mode background color */
  color: #000; /* Text color for light mode */
}
```

```html
<label for="theme" class="theme">
   <span class="theme__toggle-wrap">
    <input id="theme"
     class="theme__toggle"
     type="checkbox" role="switch"
     name="theme" value="dark">
    <span class="theme__fill"></span>
    <span class="theme__icon">
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </label>
```

Comment: I changed ‘DOMContentLoaded’ to ‘load’. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I've also replied, check below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution please:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme');

    // Function to toggle theme
    function toggleTheme() {
        if (themeToggle.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark'); 
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light'); 
        }
    }

    // Event listener for theme toggle change
    themeToggle.addEventListener('change', toggleTheme);
});
```

```css
[data-theme="dark"] {
    background-color: black; /* Dark mode background color */
    color: #fff; /* Text color for dark mode */
}

[data-theme="light"] {
    background-color: white; /* Light mode background color */
    color: #000; /* Text color for light mode */
}
```

```html
<label for="theme" class="theme">
        <span class="theme__toggle-wrap">
            <input id="theme" class="theme__toggle" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="theme">
            <span class="theme__fill"></span>
            <!-- Theme icon spans remain unchanged -->
        </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Issue with your code is of i click anywhere on there page it goes back to light theme. Even when trying to use inputs like “username” when i touch the toggle turns back to light them then i have to press username again to be able to input text.

Comment: @Awm your problem is beyond our code examples. `:not(:focus)` doesn't uncheck a `input type="checkbox"`. This example works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` CSS selector is targeting all siblings ahead of `.theme__toggle`,
however, `.theme__toggle`is inside the body and not a sibling before the `body` tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.php

replace `.theme__toggle:checked ~ body` with `body:has(.theme__toggle:checked)`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme');

    // Function to toggle theme
    function toggleTheme() {
        if (themeToggle.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        }
    }

    // Event listener for theme toggle change
    themeToggle.addEventListener('change', toggleTheme);
});
```

```css
body:has(.theme__toggle:checked) {
  background-color: black; /* Dark mode background color */
  color: #fff; /* Text color for dark mode */
}

/* Light mode */
body:has(.theme__toggle:not(:checked)) {
  background-color: white; /* Light mode background color */
  color: #000; /* Text color for light mode */
}
```

```html
  <label for="theme" class="theme">
   <span class="theme__toggle-wrap">
    <input id="theme"
     class="theme__toggle"
     type="checkbox" role="switch"
     name="theme" value="dark">
    <span class="theme__fill"></span>
    <span class="theme__icon">
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
     <span
      class="theme__icon-part"></span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </label>
```

Here's the support table for `:has` https://caniuse.com/css-has

Alternatively, to use your original `~`selector, you would need to flatten the input field and style a .container.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme');

    // Function to toggle theme
    function toggleTheme() {
        if (themeToggle.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        }
    }

    // Event listener for theme toggle change
    themeToggle.addEventListener('change', toggleTheme);
});
```

```css
.theme__toggle:checked ~ .container {
  background-color: black; /* Dark mode background color */
  color: #fff; /* Text color for dark mode */
}

/* Light mode */
.theme__toggle:not(:checked) ~ .container {
  background-color: white; /* Light mode background color */
  color: #000; /* Text color for light mode */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}

body > [class*=theme] { /* removing from the layout flow */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
}


.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 
<label for="theme" class="theme">
</label>
<input id="theme"
       class="theme__toggle"
       type="checkbox" role="switch"
       name="theme" value="dark">
<span class="theme__fill"></span>
<span class="theme__icon">
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
  <span
        class="theme__icon-part"></span>
</span>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Issue with your code is of i click anywhere on there page it goes back to light theme. Even when trying to use inputs like “username” when i touch the toggle turns back to light them then i have to press username again to be able to input text.

Comment: Did you test the provided [Run code snippet]? HTML state will persist unless you are refreshing the page or trying to use it on your project that has some type of rendering logic.

Comment: I tested it. When pressing the toggle only it switches between light/dark theme. However, when in dark-theme if i touch anywhere on the page it switches back to light (not pressing the toggle just anywhere else on the page. So the issue is dark theme doesnt stay lets say click on any part of the page away from toggle button.

Comment: This would only be true if the entire page was the checkbox, which is not the case. What device/browser are you getting this result?